Upgrading from .NET 6 to .NET 8: getting InvalidOperationException: "The service collection cannot be modified because it is read-only")
Not a Duplicate
This question is not a duplicate of The service collection cannot be modified because it is read-only: In my code I'm not doing anything to builder.Services after var app = builder.Build();
The Problem
I am upgrading an ASP.NET Core Web API project in C# from .NET 6 to .NET 8. All I did was change
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Configurations>Debug;Release;StoutBI;UAT</Configurations>
</PropertyGroup>

to
<TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>

In other projects that we've upgraded, this has been sufficient to get things to compile and work.
In this project the code compiles but every time I call an endpoint, I get the following exception:

System.InvalidOperationException: The service collection cannot be modified because it is read-only.
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollection.ThrowReadOnlyException()
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollection.System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceDescriptor>.Add(ServiceDescriptor item)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions.AddTransient(IServiceCollection services, Type serviceType, Type implementationType)
at  Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.OptionsBuilderExtensions.ValidateOnStart[TOptions](OptionsBuilder1 optionsBuilder)   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MetricsServiceExtensions.AddMetrics(IServiceCollection services)   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.HttpClientFactoryServiceCollectionExtensions.AddHttpClient(IServiceCollection services)   at Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthenticationBuilderWithConfiguration.<EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi>b__1_0(ConfidentialClientApplicationOptions options)   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory1.Create(String name)
at System.Lazy1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)   at System.Lazy1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
at System.Lazy1.CreateValue()   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache1.GetOrAdd[TArg](String name, Func3 createOptions, TArg factoryArgument)   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor1.Get(String name)
at Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthenticationBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.b__0(OpenIdConnectOptions options, IMergedOptionsStore mergedOptionsMonitor, IOptionsMonitor1 ccaOptionsMonitor, IOptions1 ccaOptions)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigureNamedOptions4.Configure(String name, TOptions options)   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory1.Create(String name)
at System.Lazy1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)   --- End of stack trace from previous location ---   at System.Lazy1.CreateValue()
at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache1.GetOrAdd[TArg](String name, Func3 createOptions, TArg factoryArgument)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor1.Get(String name)   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler1.InitializeAsync(AuthenticationScheme scheme, HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandlerProvider.GetHandlerAsync(HttpContext context, String authenticationScheme)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

The exact stacktrace varies a little bit based on the endpoint invoked, but the exception is the same every time (the part above --- End of stack trace from previous location ---).
Has something changed in .NET 8 in the way the app is to be built & configured? Or has something changed in the libraries such that they are setting themselves up differently?
Here's the bulk of the code in my Program.cs (unchanged from .NET 6):
DbContextOptionsBuilder<ReadWriteContext> optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ReadWriteContext>();
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(InternalApiUtil.DbConnectionString);
            
// Add manually constructed DbContext
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new ReadWriteContext(optionsBuilder.Options));
builder.Services.AddScoped<UserService, UserService>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IChartsService, ChartsService>();

builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add<GlobalActionFilter>();
}).AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.DictionaryKeyPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
});
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(CORS_POLICY_NAME, builder =>
    {
        builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
    });
});

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer(); // I've tried with this line commented-out: no difference
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>));
builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(MyCacheService<>));
builder.Services.AddMemoryCache(opt =>
{
    opt.SizeLimit = 1024;
});
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(ProfileFactory.CustomProfiles);

string[] initialScopes = { "Group.Read.All", "User.Read.All" };
IConfigurationSection azureAd = builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd");
builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddJwtBearer()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(azureAd)
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
    .AddMicrosoftGraph()
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();


var app = builder.Build();
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseCors(CORS_POLICY_NAME);
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

#if DEBUG
app.Run(InternalApiUtil.LOCAL_SERVER_URL);
#else
app.Run();
#endif
if (baseRule != null && InternalApiUtil.LogDebugStatements)
{
    baseRule.EnableLoggingForLevel(NLog.LogLevel.Debug);
}
logger.Info("Ready to run.");

I'm running the code in DEBUG mode when I get these errors. Using Easy Auth in Test/Production deployment.
Other Things Tried
Rather than doing things manually, I tried using the .NET Upgrade Assistant, but it makes exactly the same changes.
I also upgraded all the packages as suggested by NuGet, but with the exact same result.

"I also upgraded all the packages as suggested by NuGet" Are you sure? https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/issues/2448
